Data Model Issue: the query is returning instances of records not in the selection path
I am creating a graph data model and loading a csv file in neo4j aura.
Below is few rows in my csv file and the script to create the data model.
My issue is when querying the data model for a specific Area, it returns the Crime Count/Victimisation for the other areas.
Can you please advise on how I should model numerical data that I will use later on for aggregations and for comparisons?
ANZSOC Group,YYYY,Territorial Authority,Area Unit,Victimisations
Aggravated Robbery,2024,Auckland,Glen Innes North,4
Aggravated Sexual Assault,2024,Auckland,Glamorgan,1
Blackmail and Extortion,2024,Auckland,Glen Innes North,4
Common Assault,2024,Auckland,Glen Innes North,2
Illegal Use of a Motor Vehicle,2024,Auckland,Glamorgan,5
Illegal Use of a Motor Vehicle,2024,Auckland,Glen Innes North,17
Serious Assault Not Resulting in Injury,2024,Auckland,Glen Innes North,3
Serious Assault Resulting in Injury,2024,Auckland,Glen Innes North,7
"Theft (Except Motor Vehicles), N.E.C.",2024,Auckland,Glamorgan,1
"Theft (Except Motor Vehicles), N.E.C.",2024,Auckland,Glen Innes North,7
Theft From a Person (Excluding By Force),2024,Auckland,Glen Innes North,1
Theft of Motor Vehicle Parts or Contents,2024,Auckland,Glamorgan,4
Theft of Motor Vehicle Parts or Contents,2024,Auckland,Glen Innes North,17
"Unlawful Entry With Intent/Burglary, Break and Enter",2024,Auckland,Glamorgan,7
"Unlawful Entry With Intent/Burglary, Break and Enter",2024,Auckland,Glen Innes North,34

Below is the script to create the data model:
pre_ingest:
  - CREATE CONSTRAINT crimetype_anzsocgroup IF NOT EXISTS FOR (n:CrimeType) REQUIRE n.anzsocGroup IS UNIQUE;
  - CREATE CONSTRAINT territorialauthority_cityname IF NOT EXISTS FOR (n:TerritorialAuthority) REQUIRE n.cityName IS UNIQUE;
  - CREATE CONSTRAINT areaunit_areaname IF NOT EXISTS FOR (n:AreaUnit) REQUIRE n.areaName IS UNIQUE;
files:
- chunk_size: 100
  cql: |
    WITH $dict.rows AS rows
    UNWIND rows AS row
    MERGE (n:CrimeType {anzsocGroup: row.`ANZSOC Group`})
  url: $BASE/
- chunk_size: 100
  cql: |
    WITH $dict.rows AS rows
    UNWIND rows AS row
    MERGE (n:TerritorialAuthority {cityName: row.`Territorial Authority`})
  url: $BASE/
- chunk_size: 100
  cql: |
    WITH $dict.rows AS rows
    UNWIND rows AS row
    MERGE (n:AreaUnit {areaName: row.`Area Unit`})
  url: $BASE/
- chunk_size: 100
  cql: |-
    WITH $dict.rows AS rows
    UNWIND rows AS row
    MERGE (n:CrimeEvent {year:toIntegerOrNull(row.YYYY), victimisation:toIntegerOrNull(row.Victimisations)})
  url: $BASE/
- chunk_size: 100
  cql: |
    WITH $dict.rows AS rows
    UNWIND rows as row
    MATCH (source:TerritorialAuthority {cityName: row.`Territorial Authority`})
    MATCH (target:AreaUnit {areaName: row.`Area Unit`})
    MERGE (source)-[n:HAS_SUB_REGION]->(target)
  url: $BASE/
- chunk_size: 100
  cql: |
    WITH $dict.rows AS rows
    UNWIND rows as row
    MATCH (areaUnit:AreaUnit {areaName: row.`Area Unit`})
    MATCH (crimeType:CrimeType {anzsocGroup: row.`ANZSOC Group`})
    MATCH (crimeEvent:CrimeEvent {year:toIntegerOrNull(row.YYYY), victimisation:toIntegerOrNull(row.Victimisations)})
    MERGE (areaUnit)-[c:HAS_CRIME]->(crimeType)-[t:HAS_CRIME_COUNT]->(crimeEvent)
  url: $BASE/

**Query and Query Result -- the query also returned the Victimisation Count for the the areaUnit (i.e. it returned the crime count for Glen Innes North.
I need the query to only return instances for the queries area.
**
MATCH path = (n:AreaUnit {areaName:"Glamorgan"})-[c:HAS_CRIME]->(t:CrimeType)-[:HAS_CRIME_COUNT]->(e:CrimeEvent)
RETURN path

1
(:AreaUnit {areaName: "Glamorgan"})-[:HAS_CRIME]->(:CrimeType {anzsocGroup: "Aggravated Sexual Assault"})-[:HAS_CRIME_COUNT]->(:CrimeEvent {year: 2024, victimisation: 1})
2
(:AreaUnit {areaName: "Glamorgan"})-[:HAS_CRIME]->(:CrimeType {anzsocGroup: "Illegal Use of a Motor Vehicle"})-[:HAS_CRIME_COUNT]->(:CrimeEvent {year: 2024, victimisation: 5})
3
(:AreaUnit {areaName: "Glamorgan"})-[:HAS_CRIME]->(:CrimeType {anzsocGroup: "Illegal Use of a Motor Vehicle"})-[:HAS_CRIME_COUNT]->(:CrimeEvent {year: 2024, victimisation: 17})
4
(:AreaUnit {areaName: "Glamorgan"})-[:HAS_CRIME]->(:CrimeType {anzsocGroup: "Theft (Except Motor Vehicles), N.E.C."})-[:HAS_CRIME_COUNT]->(:CrimeEvent {year: 2024, victimisation: 1})
5
(:AreaUnit {areaName: "Glamorgan"})-[:HAS_CRIME]->(:CrimeType {anzsocGroup: "Theft (Except Motor Vehicles), N.E.C."})-[:HAS_CRIME_COUNT]->(:CrimeEvent {year: 2024, victimisation: 7})
6
(:AreaUnit {areaName: "Glamorgan"})-[:HAS_CRIME]->(:CrimeType {anzsocGroup: "Theft of Motor Vehicle Parts or Contents"})-[:HAS_CRIME_COUNT]->(:CrimeEvent {year: 2024, victimisation: 4})
7
(:AreaUnit {areaName: "Glamorgan"})-[:HAS_CRIME]->(:CrimeType {anzsocGroup: "Theft of Motor Vehicle Parts or Contents"})-[:HAS_CRIME_COUNT]->(:CrimeEvent {year: 2024, victimisation: 17})
8
(:AreaUnit {areaName: "Glamorgan"})-[:HAS_CRIME]->(:CrimeType {anzsocGroup: "Unlawful Entry With Intent/Burglary, Break and Enter"})-[:HAS_CRIME_COUNT]->(:CrimeEvent {year: 2024, victimisation: 7})
9
(:AreaUnit {areaName: "Glamorgan"})-[:HAS_CRIME]->(:CrimeType {anzsocGroup: "Unlawful Entry With Intent/Burglary, Break and Enter"})-[:HAS_CRIME_COUNT]->(:CrimeEvent {year: 2024, victimisation: 34})

I need the query to only return instances for the area I querying. So for my example above, I need the query to only return the Crime Types and Crime Count for Area = "Glamorgan".

I changed my data model to store the Area in the HAS_CRIME_COUNT relationship.  Here's my updated cScript -- will this be the proper way to model this data?  Thanks!
WITH $dict.rows AS rows
UNWIND rows as row
MATCH (areaUnit:AreaUnit {areaName: row.`Area Unit`})
MATCH (crimeType:CrimeType {anzsocGroup: row.`ANZSOC Group`})
MATCH (crimeEvent:CrimeEvent {year:toIntegerOrNull(row.YYYY), victimisation:toIntegerOrNull(row.Victimisations)})
MERGE (areaUnit)-[c:HAS_CRIME {areaUnit:row.`Area Unit`}]-(crimeType)-[t:HAS_CRIME_COUNT {areaUnit:row.`Area Unit`}]-(crimeEvent)


You should avoid storing redundant data. See my proposed answer for one way to address your situation.

@cybersam thanks for taking the time to respond.  I will give your proposed data model a try.  Cheers!

Your data model, (:AreaUnit)-[:HAS_CRIME]->(:CrimeType)-[:HAS_CRIME_COUNT]->(:CrimeEvent), does not support your use case. That is because every crime type has a unique CrimeType node, so each CrimeType node has outgoing HAS_CRIME_COUNT relationships for all area units.
One way to fix this is to eliminate the CrimeType nodes, and put type and year properties in CrimeEvent. This would allow you to simplify your data model to: (:AreaUnit)-[:HAS_CRIME]->(:CrimeEvent {type: ..., year: ..., count: ...}).
In addition, you can greatly simplify and speed up your script as well by consolidating all the separate queries into one, so that you would only need to make one pass through the data and also eliminate all the MATCHes. Here is a simplified script with my proposed data model:
pre_ingest:
  - CREATE CONSTRAINT territorialauthority_cityname IF NOT EXISTS FOR (n:TerritorialAuthority) REQUIRE n.cityName IS UNIQUE;
  - CREATE CONSTRAINT areaunit_areaname IF NOT EXISTS FOR (n:AreaUnit) REQUIRE n.areaName IS UNIQUE;
files:
  url: $BASE/
- chunk_size: 1000
  cql: |
    WITH $dict.rows AS rows
    UNWIND rows as row
    MERGE (ta:TerritorialAuthority {cityName: row.`Territorial Authority`})
    MERGE (au:AreaUnit {areaName: row.`Area Unit`})
    MERGE (ta)-[:HAS_SUB_REGION]->(au)
    MERGE (ce:CrimeEvent {year: toIntegerOrNull(row.YYYY), type: row.`ANZSOC Group`, count: toIntegerOrNull(row.Victimisations)})
    MERGE (au)-[c:HAS_CRIME]->(ce)
  url: $BASE/

With that data model, the query for your use case would be simply:
MATCH path = (n:AreaUnit {areaName:"Glamorgan"})-[c:HAS_CRIME]->(e:CrimeEvent)
RETURN path

or just:
MATCH (n:AreaUnit {areaName:"Glamorgan"})-[c:HAS_CRIME]->(e:CrimeEvent)
RETURN n, COLLECT(e) AS crimeEvents

Finally, since this proposal eliminates the CrimeType label, if one of your other use cases requires finding all instances of a crime type [via MATCH (ce:CrimeEvent {type: ...})], that would be done efficiently if you first created an index on CrimeEvent.type in your pre_ingest section.

Thanks for replying.  I will give this a try.  Cheers!
